# Break PHP loop and change HTML

Tags: php

I have built a cool script which opens a CSV and outputs the data into an HTML table - neat! :-)

However, I was wondering, is it possible to take the first row of data (table headings) and put these inside a `thead` and `th` elements?

```
<?php
    echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>\n\n";
    $f = fopen("users.csv", "r");
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        $row = "<tr>";
        $is_empty = false;
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
            if ($cell !== '') {
                $row .= "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
            } else {
                $is_empty = true;
            }
        }
        $row .= "</tr>\n";
        if ($is_empty) {
            continue;
        } else {
            echo $row;
        }
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo "\n</table>";
?>
```

Right now my HTML is:

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
<tr><td>Forename</td><td>Surname</td><td>Extension</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>Carey</td><td>9843</td></tr>
</table>
```

Can I change this to:

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
<thead><tr><th>Forename</th><th>Surname</th><th>Extension</th></tr></thead>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>Carey</td><td>9843</td></tr>
</table>
```

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add first line identifier in your code

```
<?php
    echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>\n\n";
    $f = fopen("users.csv", "r");

    $first_line=false;

    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        $row ="";

        if($first_line == false) {
             $row = "<thead><tr>";
             $col= "th";
        }
        else {
             $row = "<tr>";
             $col= "td";
        }


        $is_empty = false;

        foreach ($line as $cell) {
            if ($cell !== '') {
                $row .= "<".$col.">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</".$col.">";
            } else {
                $is_empty = true;
            }
        }


        if($first_line == false) $row .= "</tr></thead>";
        else $row .= "</tr>";

        $first_line=true;

        if ($is_empty) {
            continue;
        } else {
            echo $row;
        }
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo "\n</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Excellent! :-) Is it possible to replace `<td>` with `<th>` when it's inside `thead`?

Comment: Fantastic, Haresh!! :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter to detect that you're displaying the first line :

```
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>\n\n";
$f = fopen("users.csv", "r");
$counter = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    if ($counter == 0) {
        $row .= "<thead><tr>";
        $is_empty = false;
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
            if ($cell !== '') {
                $row .= "<th>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</th>";
            } else {
                $is_empty = true;
            }
        }
        $row .= "</tr></thead>\n";
    } else {
        $row .= "<tr>";
        $is_empty = false;
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
            if ($cell !== '') {
                $row .= "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
            } else {
                $is_empty = true;
            }
        }
        $row .= "</tr>\n";
    }

    $counter++;
    if ($is_empty) {
        continue;
    } else {
        echo $row;
    }
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the 1st line is always the header you can use a counter for lines.

```
$rowCounter = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    $tr = '<tr>';
    $td = '<td>';
    $tr_end = '</tr>';
    $td_end = '</td>';
    if ( ++$rowCounter == 1 ){
        $tr = '<thead><tr>';
        $td = '<th>';
        $tr_end = '</tr></thead>';
        $td_end = '</th>';
    }
... your code ...
}
```

Now you can use these variables inside your code. There could be several other solutions.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It would be tidier if you generate the markup text separately using a function.

```
function tr($data, $head = false, $xssProtect = true){
    // Formatting
    $cellFmt = $head? "<th>%s</th>": "<td>%s</td>";
    $rowFmt = $head? "<thead><tr>%s</tr></thead>": "<tr>%s</tr>";
    $returnFmt = sprintf($rowFmt, str_repeat($cellFmt, count($data)));

    // XSS
    if ($xssProtect) $data = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $data);

    // Format and return output
    return vsprintf($returnFmt, $data);
}


echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>\n\n";
$f = fopen("users.csv", "r");
$line_no = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo tr($line, !$line_no);
    $line_no++;
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table>";
```